# Refresh browser cause files' path changed

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I use vue-router to control my route,in normal pages,when I refresh my browser it doesn't make any mistake. but when i use parmas in route. My files are redirect to this router below.

My route.js like this

```
{
    path: '/user/:id',
    component: (resolve) => require(['./template/user.vue'], resolve),
    meta:{
        title:'Personal',
    }
}
```

Before I Refresh Browser,the files link like this
  `http://127.0.0.1:8888/dist/main.css`

After I refresh my browser,the files route turn to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/dist/main.css`

Is there any auto route in vue-router?

Comment: can you show the code for linking css file in the project?

Comment: Yes，I used webpack to build page , in my index.html page ,I use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/main.css"> ` to link style. And my directory structure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUZzl.png)

Comment: can you post your webpack config file?

Comment: also, remove the .(dot) in <link href  /> , just keep href="/dist/main.css" without .(dot) and verify

Comment: Thanks ,I tried to move .(dot)  and it works .But why it will influences just after I refresh  my browser

Comment: post your full code in github and comment the link here. i will analyze and provide you the details.

Comment: Ok , My code address is `https://github.com/ChadQi/BaseVueFrame.git` .A little big ~~

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, It's really helpful

Comment: thanks. i have updated the answer with few details at the end. check that too.

Comment: Ok, I'll see it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing right now is because of this router setting in `src/main.js`

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: Routers,
})
```

if you use `mode: 'hash'` then everything would work fine. You need not change anything in `<link href />` . You can keep the .(dot).

`mode: 'history'` option enables to have a clean url
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index

`mode: 'hash'` option enables to have a `#` in the url 
http://127.0.0.1:8888/#/index

**How `mode : 'hash'` works?**

`mode : 'hash'` makes use of default browser behavior which is to prevent http request from triggering the details that exists after `#` in the url. This is how Single Page Applications work.

When you trigger `http://127.0.0.1:8888/#/index` **Two things will happen**

1.`http://127.0.0.1:8888` will be triggered and server will receive this request

2.The parameters after `#` is not sent to the server. `/index` will remain in the browser

Once response is received from the server `http://127.0.0.1:8888` , the route `/index` will be invoked. As this route is configured in the `routeconfig` , the corresponding component will be invoked and you will see that particular component in the browser.

i hope you understood what `mode : 'hash'` does.

**How `mode : 'history'` works?**

**There are two cases here**

**Case 1**

When you refresh the browser or manually trigger this url from the browser http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/23452345

The server receives the entire url and looks for the corresponding route mapping in the server. But according to the code which you have implemented, the route `/user/23452345` will be recognized only by the browser. You don't have any logic to handle this route on the server. So you get empty page in the browser when you trigger this.

*This is how browser normally behaves*

**Case 2**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/23452345
```

if you trigger this above url from the vue code rendered in the browser then vue will recognize the request and invoke the `routerconfig`. That is why you don't face any issues during route change in this scenario.

if you want to desperately use `mode : 'history'` one way is to use a real  server (say for example nodejs), and then configure the server to return  `http://127.0.0.1:8888` for all the requests and then handle it in the `vuejs routeconfig` . And ofcourse this is not recommended.

i hope you understood the difference between `mode: 'hash'` and `mode 'history'`.
if you want more details then you can take a look at vuejs official documentation  https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#routes

i'm repeating what i said at the beginning, **to fix your code**

if you use `mode: 'hash'` then everything would work fine. You need not change anything in `<link href />` . You can keep the .(dot).

i would recommend taking a look at nuxtjs to avoid all these complications.

**This is just a comment** You have uploaded `nodemodules/` directory in git. it is not necessary to upload that. `package.json` will  enable developers to maintain the details of packages used in a project.A simple `npm install` will download all the packages. This will make uploading `nodemodules/` directory unnecessary. Also we don't want anything unnecessary to be stored in the source code repository.

i hope this was useful.

**Update**

(i didnt explain your another question on why removing .(dot) fixed the issue, here is the explanation)

**coming down to your question** , removing .(dot) fixed your issue, right!!. i will tell you why

.(dot) refers to current directory.
if your url is http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/23452345, then the complete url for `href="./dist/main.css"` will be `http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/dist/main.css` because it starts from current directory

This is the same for `build.js` too.

But if you remove the dot, then the complete url for `href` will be `http://127.0.0.1:8888/dist/main.css` because current directory is not mentioned here, so `/dist/main.css` is added to the base url path. URL path is just a directory path.